# How to replace entire Flowfile content?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to start with one Flowfile body text and then completely replace it during the course of my process. How do I replace the entire Flowfile content with some new static content?

James

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many processors which can manipulate the content of a flowfile, but the simplest processors would be [`GenerateFlowFile`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile/index.html) (to create a flowfile with custom static/dynamic text) and [`ReplaceText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) (to replace the content of an existing flowfile). For `ReplaceText`, you can use a matching regex pattern for *Search Value* of `^(.*)$` to match all characters in the incoming flowfile content and replace it with whatever static (or dynamic via [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)) content you like.

Comment: A more performant option when you always want to replace the content is to set the "Replacement Strategy" to "Always Replace". It will ignore the search value and just replace everything.